# jQuery submit, how can I know what submit button was pressed?

Tags: jquery, plugins, submit

I'm using ajaxSubmit plugin to send Ajax forms, but for some reason this plugin doesn't send names/values of `input[type=image]`'s. So now I'm catching the submit event before ajaxSubmit will handle the form and I need to know if it is possible to find out what button was pressed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("input .button-example").click(function(){
//do something with $(this) var
});
```

PS: do you have jQuery controling the $ var? Otherwise you have to do this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("input .button-example").click(function(){
    //do something with jQuery(this) var
       alert(jQuery(this));
    });
});
```

if you wan't control on event (form submit)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formid").submit(function() {
          alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
          return false;
    });
});
```

tell me something if it worked ;)

Comment: I used something like that. I binded click to that other button and added hidden field to, so now server gets proper information...

Answer (score 19):

This will catch whichever input element initiated the submit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target = null;
    $('#form :input').focus(function() {
        target = this;
        alert(target);
    });
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        alert(target);
    });
});
```

Comment: This works way better if you do `$('#form :input').click(function() {` with `click` instead of `focus`.

Comment: click will not be triggered if you press return.. may be you need to use [...].bind('click focus', function() {[...]})[...]

Answer (score 5):

This is what I am using (slight variation on the others, using mouseup and keyup events instead of focus):

```
var submitButton = undefined;
$('#your-form-id').find(':submit').live('mouseup keyup',function(){
    submitButton  = $(this);
});
$('#your-form-id').submit(function() {
    console.log(submitButton.attr('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is what I think would be a more comprehensive example of how to accomplish what you asked. You should replace the "**#your-form**" with your id form and replace "**Button One**" & "**Button Two**" with the values on your form buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var target = null;
  $('#your-form-id :input').focus(function() {
    target = $(this).val();
  });
  $('#your-form-id').submit(function() {

    if (target == 'Button One') {
      alert (target);
    }
    else if (target == 'Button Two') {
      alert (target);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it. I was inspired by some of the answers posted above but I needed an approach that would work for all my forms since I loaded them dynamically.

I noticed that the ajaxSubmit had a `data` option which described by the plugin does the following:

> An object containing extra data that should be submitted along with
>   the form.

This is exactly what we need.

So I attached the click handler on my submit buttons and saved the element using jQuery (I prefer this method than adding a fake attribute):

```
$('[type="submit"]').live('click', function(e){
        jQuery.data( $(this).parents('form')[0], 'submitTrigger', $(this).attr('name'));
});
```

And then in my ajaxSubmit call I built the data object and sent it like this:

```
function dialogFormSubmit( form ) {
    var data = {}
    data[jQuery.data( form, 'submitTrigger')] = true;
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({ 
        data: data
    });
    return false;
}
```

I built the data object that way because I wanted it to behave the same way as if I would have submitted it with vanilla HTML/PHP (name of the input is the key in the $_POST array). I suppose if I wanted to stay true to its real behaviour I would have added the value or innerHTML of the submit button but I usually just check if it's set so it was unncessary :).

Comment: by far the best answer i've seen.

Answer (score 2):

I found this very useful. It covers the case of clicking, and also submitting with tab index and hitting space or enter. It captures the last input before a submit was made, and that's the button which submitted, so you can have several buttons and check each as a target to perform something unique.

```
$('#form input').live('focusin focusout mouseup', function() {
    // Add a data attribute to the form and save input as last selected
    $('#form').data('lastSelected', $(this));
});
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var last = $(this).data('lastSelected').get(0);
    var target = $('#button').get(0);
    console.log(last);
    console.log(target);
    // Verify if last selected was our target button
    if (last == target) {
        console.log('bingo');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clickedVar = null;
    $('#form :submit').focus(function() {
         clickedVar = $(this).attr("name");
         alert(clickedVar);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the answer did not convince me so much here to bring an alternative.
What I will do is verify by JS which button was pressed.

```
<head>
<script>
$('body').click(function(event) {
     var log = $('#log');
     if($(event.target).is('#btn1')) {
        log.html(event.target.id + ' was clicked.');
        return false;
    }else{
        if($(event.target).is('#btn2')) {
           log.html(event.target.id + ' was clicked.');
           return false;
              }
         }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="formulario"  method="post">
      <div id="log"></div>
      <input type="submit" id="btn1" value="Btn 01">
      <input type="submit" id="btn2" value="Btn 02">
  </form>
</body>
```

Use this page to make the test [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/h722g/1/)

Saludos

Comment: This won't work when you sumbit a form using keyboard.