# How do I handle Two Submit buttons on One Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have two submit buttons and one form.  How do I check what submit button was selected in my jquery code?

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UserInfo", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id  = "formNext" })) { %> 
.... 
<input id="submitHome" type="submit" name="goHome" value="Home" />  
<input id="submitNext" type="submit" name="getNext" value="Next" /> 
<% } %>


$(document).ready(function() {       
$('#formNext').submit(function() {      
        //Code Does not work but looking at something like this...
        //$('#submitHome').click(function() {
        //      navigate to Home;
        //});
        //$('#submitNext').click(function() {
        //      return true;
        //});
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this old question help out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154039/jquery-submit-how-can-i-know-what-submit-button-was-pressed

Comment: You should probably use buttons instead of submit inputs.

Comment: Why did you delete your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366104/compatibility-view-kills-my-style-sheet-what-to-do)?

Comment: @BalusC - It was a question that really had no answer, based on what I was trying to do.  I didnt want to have it up to confuse.  Sorry :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$('#submitHome').click(function() {
      //navigate to Home;
});
$('#submitNext').click(function() {
      return true;
});
```

These should work if you pull them outside of the form.submit().  (right now those handlers are being attached after the form is submitted, which is too late since the click has already occurred)

Comment: If the user uses keyboard to submit, this doesn't work

Answer (score 10):

You can try something like this

```
$(function() {
 var buttonpressed;
 $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
      buttonpressed = $(this).attr('name')
 })
 $('form').submit(function() {
      alert('button clicked was ' + buttonpressed)
        buttonpressed=''
    return(false)
 })
})
```

Source: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/determining-which-of-two-submit-buttons-were-clicked-in-a-single-form

Comment: If the user uses keyboard to submit, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
  $(".submitButton").click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr("name"));
  });
});​
```

[Working demo behind the link.](http://jsbin.com/inuha/edit)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UserInfo", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formNext" })) { %>
....
<input id="submitHome" type="submit" name="goHome" value="Home" />
<input id="submitNext" type="submit" name="getNext" value="Next" />
<% } %>


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitHome').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the page to do the usuall onclick event (from reloading the page)
    // navigate to Home;
  });
  $('#submitNext').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // return true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two action methods and that handles two post seperately that takes formcollection as param.
Add two input with type=button and bind the click event with $.post to your action method with values from the form controls you need for that post.