# How can I know client side which submit button causes submit when the submit button has been triggered?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms

I'm using asp.net form. If a submit button is clicked I check his identity by doing

```
$('form').submit(function(e)
    {
        // VALIDAZIONE CAMPI LOGIN
        if(e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.id
```

But.. It doesn't work if the submit button isn't clicked, but triggered.
In a few words.. 
How can I know which submit button causes submit when the submit button has been triggered?

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="send1" value="Confirm" />
    <input type="submit" name="send2" value="Confirm2" />

    <input type="button" name="button2" />
</form>

$(function() {
    $('input[name="button2"]').click(function() {
        ('input[name="send2"]').trigger('click');
    });

    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        if (e... 
"this is the point where I want to know which of the submit button has been triggered"
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery submit, how can I know what submit..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154039/jquery-submit-how-can-i-know-what-submit-button-was-pressed).

Answer (score 2):

Your solution does work you just havent defined the id attribute on your submit button. If you do that this line of code should work

```
e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.id
```

and if you do not want to use the id attribute and the name instead change it to

```
e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.name
```

see example below

http://jsfiddle.net/VVgYK/

Comment: You're right. I had to write the ID or use de name but in trigger case they are not initialized with the attributes of the triggered submit button

Comment: @Mino are you saying that the sumbit input tags are not initialized with attributes ? If yes how exactly are you initializing them?