# jquery click function inside form submit function

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form with number of submit type as images. Each image has a different title. I need to find out the title of the clicked image. But my click function inside form submit is not working.

My form is:

```
  <form action='log.php' id='logForm' method='post' >
  <?
   for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++)
   {
    ?>
   <input type="image" src="<?=$img;?>" title="<?=$url;?> id="<?="image".$j?> class="images" />
    <?
    }
    ?>
   </form>
```

Jquery:

```
    $("#logForm").submit(function(e)
    {


  $(".advt_image").click(function(event) {
        var href=event.target.title;
    });





           var Form = { };
            Form['inputFree'] = $("#inputFree").val();
         //   if($("#freeTOS").is(":checked"))
                    Form['freeTOS'] = '1';

            $(".active").hide().removeClass('active');
            $("#paneLoading").show().addClass('active');


var url="http://"+href;

      $.post('processFree.php', Form, function(data)
            {
                    if(data == "Success")
                    {
                            $("#FreeErrors").html('').hide();
                            swapToPane('paneSuccess');

                     setTimeout( function() {  location=url }, 2500 );


                    return;




                    }

                    swapToPane('paneFree');
                    $("#FreeErrors").html(data).show();
            });

            return false;
    });
```

How can I get the title value of clicked image inside this `$("#logForm").submit(function())`?

How can I use the id of clicked image for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `event.target` property

```
$("#logForm").submit(function(e)
    alert($(e.target).attr('title'));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

**[UPDATE]**

I just realized it wouldn't work. I don't think there is a simple solution to this. You have to track the click event on the input and use it later.

[jQuery submit, how can I know what submit button was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154039/jquery-submit-how-can-i-know-what-submit-button-was-pressed)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target = null;
    $('#form :input[type="image"]').click(function() {
        target = this;
        alert(target);
    });
    $('#form').submit(function() {
        alert($(target).attr('title'));
    });
});
```

[Update 2] - `.focus` is not working, but `.click` is working
http://jsfiddle.net/gjSJh/1/

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am new to jquery. could you please give me an example? can I use this event.target inside  $("#logForm").submit(function()
{});  ?

Comment: Sorry..alert message is blank :(

Comment: The target of submit event will be the form.  how it can be the image button?

Comment: @Zendie - Did you see my update? The JSFiddle example is working.

Comment: Yes..i have seen..but couldn't get the title yet. :(

Comment: Click on the input field and it will alert the title.

Answer (score 0):

The way i see it, you have multiple submit buttons. Instead of calling the function on submit, call it on the click of these buttons so you can easily access the one the user chose:

```
$('input.images').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the default submit from occuring
    alert($(this).attr('title');

   //do your other functions here.

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check following code you can get the title of clicked image.

**Single click**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#logForm').submit(function(e){
         $(".images").click(function(event) {
            alert(event.target.title);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

**Double click**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#logForm').submit(function(e){
         $(".images").dblclick(function(event) {
            alert(event.target.title);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: .images is class of input type images?

Comment: Ya you can get the title of clicked images using class

Comment: Plz complete double cot of title and id of images in your for loop

Comment: yes, I have corrected title quote. But click event is not working within $('#logForm').submit(function(e){
}

Comment: Can you update your code in question so i can see.I have tested this code and its works for me Plz check properly

Comment: Hi, I need double click to show the alert message. What will be the problem?

Comment: Declare href variable globally instead of click function because you can use this local variable outside the function

Answer (score 0):

// Runtime click event for all elements

```
$(document).on('vclick', '.control', function (e) { // .control is classname of the elements
    var control = e.target;
    alert(e.currentTarget[0].id);
});
```

if you are not getting proper message in alert, just debug using Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

add following ondomready in your rendering page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form input[type=image]").click(function() {
        $("input[type=image]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
        $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
    });
});
```

Now in your form's submitt action add follwing behaviour and yupeee!... you got it!....

```
$("#logForm").submit(function(e)
    {
        var title = $("input[type=image][clicked=true]",e.target).attr("title");
        .....
        .....
    });
```